Imprints of the spherical harmonic quantum numbers
The spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator on the sphere, i.e. $$\Delta Y_{lm}=-l(l+1) Y_{lm}.$$
The peculiar property for the quantum numbers $l\in {0,1,2,\cdots}$ and $m\in {-l,-l+1,...,0,...,l-1,l}$ is the structuring principle for atomic orbitals and therefore for the periodic table of elements.
Another application can be found in cosmology, where the powerspectrum as a function of $l$ is also used to analyse the fluctuations of the cosmic microwave background.
I wonder, whether someone can provide an necessarily incomplete list of outstanding applications to science (besides atomic orbitals), where these quantum numbers $l$ and $m$ play a crucial role for understanding.

https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.30#iv

Since the spherical harmonics are analogous to Fourier series (every function on the surface of a sphere can be expressed as a sum of these spherical harmonics) one would expect the list of applications to be innumerable. (Just as is the case with Fourier series which are ubiquitous). A few could include:

The electromagnetic Schumann resonances of the earth, the "fundamental mode" being close to 8Hz Schumann Resonance Derivation

Calculating the electrostatic potential - on this very site there is a question and answer relating to this: Finding potential using spherical harmonics, URL (version: 2021-07-25): Finding potential using spherical harmonics

Geomagnetism: see The magnetic field of the earth

Astroseismology: see Astroseismology


One can also get similar `quantum numbers' from systems whose solutions involve spherical bessel functions such as:

Any spherical body that is resonating - for example Basketballs as spherical acoustic cavities


Seriously, this is like asking, "What are the applications of the Fourier Transform."--which reminds me of certain other questions, "too many to list".
But:
Solar Seismology:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helioseismology
Gravity:
https://cddis.nasa.gov/926/egm96/egm96.html (and the Aeroid for Mars--any gravity model. Also, if you do orbits: $J_2$.)
Animation:
https://graphics.pixar.com/library/HarmonicCoordinatesB/paper.pdf
There are also extensions to:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_harmonics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor_spherical_harmonics
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-weighted_spherical_harmonics
https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-a/a9e6a99faa3eda23704a554106399d2c
